# Import finalcut project into imovie

Tags: imovie, final-cut-pro

My finalcut pro trial expired before I could export the movie I was working on. How can I import it into imovie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't buy a new software just to do that task, so I can think in another way to achieve your goal. Send the project to someone who does have Final Cut Pro. There are always someone willing to help in a Editing Forum. It doesn't matter if the person does not have your media files, as long as he/she exports a XML file from your project, which in 99% of the time is a very little file (both the project and the resulting XML). Get that XML back and than use that file to import your timelines and connect all your media into iMovie or another decent software like Premiere or Vegas.

Plus you can use this workaround to get accurate results:

http://alex4d.com/notes/item/import-final-cut-pro-x-projects-into-imovie

### Import Final Cut Pro X projects into iMovie using hidden workaround

Editor and plugin maker [Andy Mees](http://andymees.wordpress.com/) has discovered that you can import Final Cut Pro X exported XML into the new version of iMovie. Here you can see the source timeline in Final Cut. It was exported as an .fcpxml file and imported into iMovie.

[image]

The reason why the timelines don’t match up is because iMovie timelines have variable scale. Although the faint grey vertical lines are equally spaced, the times they mark aren’t equally spaced (in this case some are marked as denoting 9.4, 10.9, 15.8, 20.3, 24.4, 27.2 and 32.1 seconds).

iMovie doesn’t implement all Final Cut Pro X features such as multiple connected video clips at the same time or auditions. Despite this, you can see iMovie displays an audition icon on one of the audio clips in Andy’s timeline. If you attempt to edit the audition in iMovie, you’ll see an imcomplete UI:

[image]

iMovie doesn’t have an ‘Import Final Cut Pro X XML…’ command. Andy discovered a simple workaround.

1. Control- or Right-click the iMovie icon and choose ‘Show Package Contents’ from the shortcut menu
2. Open another window that shows the iMovie icon and drop your .fcpxml file onto the icon.
3. In iMovie you’ll see a dialogue box that asks which iMovie library you would like to import your XML file into:

[image]

As well as reading [his blog](http://andymees.wordpress.com/), keep up with Andy by following [him on Twitter](https://twitter.com/andymees).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to import Final Cut projects into iMovie.

Attempting to open the Final Cut project file into iMovie will fail because it uses a different file format. There is also no way to convert this into a format iMovie will read because Final Cut has many more features and options that will not translate to iMovie.

If you still can, your best bet would be to export whatever you have in Final Cut as single video file and import that into iMovie. You will no longer have the ability to edit the composition of that clip or any effects that have been applied it to it, but it's your best bet unless you don't mind starting from scratch.

Comment: final cut pro wont start up again

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing you can do. There is absolutely no compatibility/correlation between Final Cut and iMovie. They are two entirely separate and independent pieces of software

Comment: looks like ill need another 30 day trial